# I lost Thunderbird from the Launcher and can't get it back

Tags: thunderbird

I am new to Ubuntu, am not very tech savey, and a couple of days ago I installed Kontack on my Ubuntu. About half way through the install my thunderbird icon disappeared from the Launcher on the desktop. I've been searching for where it went and how to restore it to my desktop sdince then with no luck. Can you help me find my Thunderbird program and re-set it on my launcher as my default email program?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Systems Settings* -> *Details* -> select *Default Applications* from the pane on left side -> click the little black arrow to the right of *Mail* and select Thunderbird from the dropdown menu to change the default mail application to Thunderbird.

[image]

Then search in the Dash for Thunderbird and open Thunderbird. The Thunderbird icon will appear on the Launcher. Right-click the Thunderbird icon on the Launcher and select *Lock to Launcher* to make the Thunderbird icon appear on the Launcher permanently.